# ldconfig -p Library cache disabled

Tags: shared-libraries, embedded-linux, buildroot

I'm building an embedded linux system using Buildroot. Our hardware is identical to Beagle Bone Green development board. When I added ssh, it didn't start printing:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen: can't load library 'libatomic.so.1'
Starting sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd: can't load library 'libatomic.so.1'
```

The library itself exists in the directory /usr/lib/. It seems like the system are not able to load any shared library. ldconfig -p prints:

```
Library cache disabled
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like either libatomic.so or ssh was built with an incompatible toolchain. Did you build everything within buildroot? Did you change the configuration of the toolchain without doing a 'make clean' inbetween? The ldconfig -p output is expected: buildroot doesn't use the library cache, it always searches libraries in /lib and /usr/lib.

Comment: Hi) Thanks for the reply!) I've build everything with buildroot using buildroot toolchain option. I didn't do 'make clean' when i rebuilt my rootfs though, I'll try this just now... Should my rootfs contains /etc/ld.so.cache file after rebuild?

Comment: I've rebuild zImage after 'make clean' and now libraries seem to be loaded (sshd seems to be able to start during boot). But now login prompt dissapeared, but I think it is a different problem connected with something else in the configuration

Comment: It just was ssh-keygen which was generating new host keys too long (I'm using initramfs)...